# PyTorch: Batch size and individual datum in nn.Module

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

In pytorch nn.Module, the model created seems to be agnostic of the batch size.  That is, if an individual datum is 128 dimensions, and we are training in batches of 64, the model should have an input of 128, not 128 x 64.

The first step of my `nn.Sequential` is a `Flatten`.  When I apply the model to a single datum (no batch), I need to make sure the Flatten has a `start_dim=0`.  But this is incorrect when applying to a batch.  This seems to be the opposite interface than above: you need to tailor your model to whether or not you are using batches.

So:

1. Does a `nn.Module` need to be aware of batching?
2. If yes: How do you apply the model to a single sample, without a batch?
3. If not: How do you apply Flatten, when you might send a batch, or you might send a single sample?

An equivalent question might be: **How do I build a PyTorch model to train with batches, but still apply it to individual datum at production time?**

Comment: Most built-in `nn.Module`s assume the input is batched, i.e., shaped like `[B, ...]` where `B` is the batch size. This is why `nn.Flatten` has `start_dim=1` by default (leaving dim 0 as the batch dimension). If you input a single datum `x`, you can make it a batch containing only a single item by adding a batch dimension: `x = x[None]`.

Comment: or perhaps a bit tidier: `x = x.unsqueeze(0)`